# Nested models in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, angularjs

I have stripped my problem down to the most minimal form, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ejubN/

I basically want to be able to load a large JSON object into $scope.b that gets rendered. And if any of the elements in @scope.b are changed, updated, or if a new one is created, then 'contenteditable' should be triggered to save that back to my rails application via a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fiddle shows some code that will call a listener whenever `$scope.b` changes: http://jsfiddle.net/Gloopy/SQuVy/

I may have stripped the example down too far but I'm assuming you don't need a directive and you were basing this off a sample from the AngularJS [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController). Also I changed `$scope.b` to contain javascript objects instead of primatives due to binding issues with ng-repeat described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/VD77QR1J6uQ/discussion) (which will hopefully be a better test since you're loading a large JSON object).

You should be able to do your post using the [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) though posting every time the listener fires is probably not ideal. Others may have better suggestions on when to actually do your saves but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand why you used $watch instead, but if I change your example to bind 'a.value' to a contenteditable div it stops working. I did base it off the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) you linked to and part of the reason why I based it off that was because they had a contenteditable directive.

Comment: See if this fiddle is more what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/yBA6c/1/. My fiddle didn't have the contenteditable directive which is why it didn't work when you modified it. I think your original example would have worked if you weren't binding to primatives.